# Organise collections in dope sheet

Tags: materials, objects, grease-pencil, dopesheet, layers

As seen in the image I have 3 collections FG, Chara, Stroke. I need to organise such the the FG is at top, Chara is middle and Stroke is at bottom. I would like to do so without having to move on Y axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did was dump FLASH thinking and take up AFX thinking.

I made 3 collections FG, Character and BG. And arranged the same on the Y co ordinates as per their names. That provided me the hierarchy as needed.